# reset TextView from two activities in OnReceive method

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-broadcastreceiver

I have two acitivties and want to reset values in them everyday at 00:00. 
**Question:**
 Is there any way to link two activities to onReceive method of broadcastReceiver so I can update activities(TextView and EditText) from onReceive?

Comment: Just use the same code inside the `onReceive` of both activities. Maybe using a static method in which you feed `TextView`s and `EditText`s and it clears them

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` class and register it in your manifest. Also pass the instances of your activities to the `BroadcastReceiver` when you declare it so you can know which one you are clearing/using.

Now make your clearing methods public in both of your activities and call them from your `BroadcastReceiver` using the instances of each activity.

Check [THIS](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) tutorial and [THIS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) one on how to use BroadcastReceiver class.